# how to display openweather map weather icons react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im trying to display weather icons from open weather map api , but am not entirely sure how to do it , here is the documentation    https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions .. im passing in weather.icon just like  its written in the docs but its not working for some reason ,can someone  please tell me what i  am doing wrong? thanks

app.js

```
    class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    temperature: undefined,
    city: undefined,
    country: undefined,
    pressure: undefined,
    humidity: undefined,
    description: undefined,
    rain:undefined,
    icon:undefined,
    error: undefined
  }

  handlenum1Change (evt) {



let temp = (evt.target.value);




}


 getWeather = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = e.target.city.value;

    const api_call = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`);
    const data = await api_call.json();
    console.log(data)
    if (city) {
      this.setState({
        temperature: data.main.temp,
        city: data.name,

        icon: data.weather.icon,
        rain: data.rain,
        pressure: data.main.pressure,
        humidity: data.main.humidity,
        description: data.weather[0].description,
        error: ""
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        temperature: undefined,
        city: undefined,
        country: undefined,
        humidity: undefined,
        description: undefined,
        pressure:undefined,
        rain : undefined,
        error: "Please enter the values."
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="main">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-5 title-container">

                </div>
                <div className="col-xs-7 form-container">
                  <form onSubmit={this.getWeather} >

                  <input type="text" name="city" onChange={this.handlenum1Change} placeholder="City..."/>

    <button>Get Weather</button>
    </form>


                  <Weather 
                    temperature={this.state.temperature} 
                    humidity={this.state.humidity}
                    city={this.state.city}
                       pressure={this.state.pressure}
                    description={this.state.description}
                    rain={this.state.rain}
                    icon={this.state.icon}
                    error={this.state.error}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default App;
```

weather.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Weather = props =>
  <div>
    <p>{props.city}</p> 

        <p> humidity {props.humidity }</p> 

        <p> {props.description} </p>
    <p> temperature {props.temperature}</p> 
     <p> atmospheric pressure : {props.pressure}</p> 
 <p> atmospheric pressure : {props.rain}</p> 
 <img className="img-fluid" src={props.icon} />
  </div>





export default Weather;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for you to display the icon, you need to use the URL and not just icon value. Something like this

The value returned from the API is '09d'. So you will have to append the URL with string url to have the weather api url appended with image and image extension.

{`http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${props.icon}.png`}

[image]
Few other things noticed in your code is ,

You are setting default values as undefined, which is not correct.

Please use proper value, something like

state = {
    temperature: '',
    city: ''
  }

https://codesandbox.io/s/6102m4kn3r

Comment: <img className="img-fluid" src={'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${props.icon}'.png}/>                              
                                                                                                  
 doesnt seem to work , sorry if im asking a stupid question i just started learning react

Comment: @Logitech: You have added it wrong, need to use string literals . Please check the attached image in my response for your reference. let me know if it works.

Comment: <img className="img-fluid" src={'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${this.state.icon}.png'}/>   I have added this line , now it just displays a broken image .. thanks for the help though.

Comment: it says           $%7Bprops.icon%7D.png:1 GET http://openweathermap.org/img/w/$%7Bprops.icon%7D.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Please see the sample i have created https://codesandbox.io/s/6102m4kn3r

Comment: can you please explain what this line is doing? const renderWeatherIcon = this.state.data.weather.map(item => {

Comment: we are using map function to render the response data and display it.

Comment: how come just using <img className="img-fluid" src={'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${props.icon}.png'}/> doesnt work?

Comment: do i need to create a new component and add that function ?

Comment: never mind i figured it out , turns it was passing a string instead of a value thanks so much for the help !!! really appreciate it !!

Answer (score 2):

as per your code in weather.js

```
<img src ={`http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${this.props.icon}.png`} alt="wthr img" />
```

it will display the weather icon...ie

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 class Weather extends Component {
    render() {
    return ( 
      <div>   
      <p>WeatherNow:
      <img src ={`http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${this.props.icon}.png`} 
         alt="wthr img" />
     </p>
        </div>

    );  
      }
      }

 export default Weather;
```

Comment: Please add some description of your approach or how you have solved along with the code, this helps others understand answer better.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make change in src attribute of `<img>`.
As given in Weathermap api you have to request icon by http://openweathermap.org/img/w/10d.png.
Replace `10d.png`  by `props.icon+'.png'`. It will work.

Comment: <img className="img-fluid" src={props.icon +'png'} /> like this?

Comment: tried it , its just displays broken image , thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to display the icon, you need to use the URL. Something like the below code

```
<img src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${data.weather[0].icon}.png`} height="70px" />
```

Comment: But what does it add to the answer provided five years ago?